# p2 - p1 = 2n for every 2n

Tags: prime-numbers

Quote:

"Chen's work mentioned in the discussion of the Goldbach conjecture also showed that every even number is the difference between a prime and a P2."

from: [link](https://primes.utm.edu/notes/conjectures/)

However I can't get this verified or find different sources stating the same.

so question is: is this true? where can i find proof?

thanks.

Comment: I am not sure why there ate three votes to close. Someone cares to explain?

Comment: @Joël My guess is that the perception was that this is a simple enough question that a few minutes of research could have found an answer. In this case, I double checked my own answer by typing in "Chen's theorem" into Wikipedia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two relevant papers for Chen's original proof are  Chen, J.R. (1973). "On the representation of a larger even integer as the sum of a prime and the product of at most two primes". Sci. Sinica. 16: 157–176. and  Chen, J.R. (1966). "On the representation of a large even integer as the sum of a prime and the product of at most two primes". Kexue Tongbao. 11 (9): 385–386.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chen%27s_theorem) for more details along with related strengthened results.